# Using Microsoft Access front-end with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

We are using a MS Access database at work and I am exploring the idea of using the MS Access front-end and use a Postgres back-end to better manage concurrent uses and add spatial capabilities with PostGIS extension.

I was wondering how the transition would be for end users that already uses Access to occasionally manipulate (viewing, inserting) non-spatial data with forms?

Would they actually notice that the back-end has changed?

Is this stable enough to use that combination in a productivity environment?